# weird behavior with $uibModal in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on AngularJs app where I need to show popup for ajax request on error. I am using bootstrap Modal for popup but I am facing very weird problem.

Here is my controller code

```
var upComingGroupEventsController = function ($scope, $window, $routeParams, $uibModal, $location, $filter, DataService, SharedProperties, ngDialog) {
    var groupId = $routeParams.groupid;

    var onUpcomingGroupError = function (data) {
        $scope.modalOptions.headerText = "Error";
        $scope.modalOptions.bodyText = data.statusText;


        var upcomingGroupErrorModel = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: window.serverURL + 'app/ErrorMessages/PopUpErrorMessage.html',
            controller: 'upComingGroupEventsController'
        });

        $scope.cancelForm = function () {
            upcomingGroupErrorModel.close();
        };
    };

    $scope.upComingGroupData = [];

    $scope.load = function () {

        $scope.modalOptions = {
            headerText: "",
            bodyText: ""
        }

        var onUpcomingEventsComplete = function (data) {
            $scope.upComingGroupData = data;
        };

        DataService.getListOfUpcomingEventsByGroupId(groupId)
            .then(onUpcomingEventsComplete, onUpcomingGroupError);
    };

    $scope.load();
}

angularFormsApp.controller("upComingGroupEventsController", ["$scope", "$window", "$routeParams", "$uibModal", "$location", "$filter", "DataService", "SharedProperties", "ngDialog", upComingGroupEventsController]);
```

and DataService call method below

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("m/api/Group/{groupId}/UpcomingEvents")]
        public IHttpActionResult ListOfUpcomingEventsByGroupId(string groupId)
        {
            try
            {
                int a = 1, b = 1, c = 0;
                a = b/c;
                var listOfUpcomingEvents = GroupExecutor.GetListOfUpcomingEventsByGroupId(groupId);
                return Ok(listOfUpcomingEvents);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogClass.Logger.Error(ex.Message, ex);
                return InternalServerError();
            }
        }
```

Here I am forcefully throwing exception s that I can popup on error.

But its after returning error..

1. popup is opening but blank
2. Its repeating again and again.. I mean after showing popup its again calling that dataservice and again popup so why its going in loop on error ?

Comment: What's in the  modal controller? Do you have any other $httpInterceptors pointed at this modal?

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces this. Easy enough to use a bogus url to make requests to